# Django version of flask.jsonify jsonify

Tags: json, django

I am currently trying to migrate a project from flask over to Django as practice and just to get it working on Django... I was wondering if there is a method within Django that performs the job of flask.jsonify?

If not, how else would you recommend I can emulate the same functionality?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def someView(request):
    ...
    return JsonResponse(someDictionary)
```